# AKS Ingress controller install, helm error

Tags: kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

I am very new to azure kubernetes and am just trying to get a test cluster set up. I am at the point where I need to add an ingress controller, so I am following the guide from microsoft here :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-basic?tabs=azure-powershell

I am attempting to create the ingress controller in powershell using the helm script they have in the guide :

```
helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx

$AcrUrl = (Get-AzContainerRegistry -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -Name $RegistryName).LoginServer

helm install nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx `
    --namespace kuber-ut `
    --set controller.replicaCount=2 `
    --set controller.nodeSelector."kubernetes\.io/os"=linux `
    --set controller.image.registry=$AcrUrl `
    --set controller.image.image=$ControllerImage `
    --set controller.image.tag=$ControllerTag `
    --set controller.image.digest="" `
    --set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.nodeSelector."kubernetes\.io/os"=linux `
    --set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-load-balancer-health-probe-request-path"=/healthz `
    --set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.image.registry=$AcrUrl `
    --set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.image.image=$PatchImage `
    --set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.image.tag=$PatchTag `
    --set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.image.digest="" `
    --set defaultBackend.nodeSelector."kubernetes\.io/os"=linux `
    --set defaultBackend.image.registry=$AcrUrl `
    --set defaultBackend.image.image=$DefaultBackendImage `
    --set defaultBackend.image.tag=$DefaultBackendTag `
    --set defaultBackend.image.digest=""
```

When I run this, I get the error :

```
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. Unable to continue with install: IngressClass "nginx" in namespace "" exists and cannot be imported into the current 
release: invalid ownership metadata; annotation validation error: key "meta.helm.sh/release-name" must equal "nginx-ingress": current value is "ingress-nginx"; annotation validation error: key 
"meta.helm.sh/release-namespace" must equal "kuber-ut": current value is "ingress-basic"
```

It says that the resource already exists. But in the azure portal, I see no ingress controllers. I also do not see the namespace ingress-basic. I just wanted to create an ingress controller in my namespace kuber-ut, but apparently there already is one? I just cant see it in the portal?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps:

1. Go to the PowerShell and connect to the Azure Portal by using the `az Login` command
2. After logging in to the Azure Portal` connect your AKS cluster by using the below command:

   ```
   az aks get-credentials --resource-group "your resource group name" --name "your aks cluster name"
   ```

   After connecting to the AKS cluster by using the below command, you will get your Ingress list:

   ```
   kubectl get ingress -n kuber-ut
   ```

   After getting the Ingress list, delete Ingress one and reinstall it.

   ```
   kubectl delete ingress -n kuber-ut "youringressname"
   ```

Comment: kubectl get ingress -n kuber-ut returns :
No resources found in kuber-ut namespace.

Comment: @evolmonster did you ever manage to fix this issue? We are experiencing the exact same thing.